# How can I install the latest 6.x or 7.x versions of nodejs (April 2017) on a sid/stretch system?

Tags: node.js, npm

Both the commands for node 6.x and 7.x fail with

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

The command fails with:

```
E: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x/dists/jessie/main/source/Sources  Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Is the repo broken?

I am currently on Debian Sid (stretch) and it seems some of the variables the script depends on are not the same as mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nvm is the new way of installing node js the script you are using has been depreciated so here is the way to install node js if you are on ubuntu
[image: screenshot that proves my point]
Install some dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
```

Install lib ssl

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Get nvm

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh | bash
```

Install node

```
 nvm install node
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use nvm (Node Version Manager) to install any versions of node.js

To install nvm visit this [link](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script)